# Can I change the color of the JQuery Datepicker Placeholder text?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

The title says it all. Can I change the color of the JQuery UI's Datepicker placeholder?

Datepicker For Reference: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/guez0tb9/

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Enter Date">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as described in this article: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder-shown/

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Safari, Chrome and Opera */
  color: orange;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: orange;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: orange;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: orange
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Edge */
  color: orange
}

:placeholder-shown { /* Standard one last! */
  color: orange;
}
```

And about browser compitability:

```
Chrome  Safari  Firefox  Opera  IE    Edge   Android    iOS
4+*       5+*     4+*     33+*  10+*  Yes*     Yes*     Yes*
```

*This information was taken from the very same article!

Take a look:
https://jsfiddle.net/guez0tb9/1/

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. I must have just been using the wrong keywords to find this info.

Answer (score 1):

Simple add following css:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#f00; }
::-moz-placeholder { color:#f00; } /* firefox 19+ */
:-ms-input-placeholder { color:#f00; } /* ie */
input:-moz-placeholder { color:#f00; }
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guez0tb9/2/)**

Check for [more information](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css)

Answer (score 0):

This is same as that of any input form field placeholder. 
You can use below:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    red;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    red;
   opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    red;
   opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways for changing color of placeholder's text.
Add some css in your file.

```
              <style>
               ::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
                 color:    #909;
                  opacity:  1;
                  }
               <\style>
```